# Can't connect to database when install DNN 6.0.1

Tags: sql, dotnetnuke

I have downloaded DNN 6.0.1 to install on my localhost. The environment is Win7+IIS7.5+SQL 2008 Express. I have add modify permission for NETWORK SERVICE on the folder. When I use the DefaultAppPool(.NET framework 4.0), the website doesn't work, while using ASP.NET v2.0 classic, the website works but when setting up database in stallation, there goes:

Connection Error(s):
Index #: 0
Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
Class: 13
Number: 18456
Message:
the Message item is blank.

So anybody know why and how solve this problem?

Thank,
Sean

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the app pool is running under the Network Servcie as well and that you have the proper database passwords etc.